# Ring structure of non-modular group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

I know if $k$ is a field such that $char(k)$ divides $|G|$ (a finite group), then finding the ring structure on $H^\ast(G,k)$ can be very, *very* hard.

But what about when $k=\mathbb{Z}$? Is the computation easier? I know of several "modern" techniques to compute the cohomology groups, but have never encountered a detailed computation of the ring structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answers  a previous version of the question...**

If $G$ is a finite group and $k$ is a field such that $\operatorname{char}k\nmid|G|$, then $H^p(G,k)=0$ for all $p>0$, so that the only non-zero cohomology group us $H^0(G,k)\cong k$, and in fact this isomorphism is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras.

In other words: nothing interesting happens!

Comment: ah, sorry, I messed that up. I meant to be talking about over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is no need to any «modern techniques» for this: this was known aproximately *before* group cohomology was defined :D

Comment: Sorry about that! Perhaps it is too late for me to be posting questions... :)